# How to math.floor to a decimal in Lua?

Tags: lua, floor

```
print(math.floor(12.5928))
```

The code above prints 12. What do you do to make it print 12.5?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`print(math.floor(12.5928 * 10) / 10)`

Answer (score 7):

To generalize the previous answer, this function rounds a number to any number of decimals:

```
function round(number, decimals)
    local power = 10^decimals
    return math.floor(number * power) / power
end
```

Then, `round(12.5928, 1)` gives `12.5`.

Answer (score 5):

print(string.format("%.2f", 129.65686))

Answer (score -1):

for two digits round of 
print(math.floor((12.5928) * 100) / 100)